# Reading new messages from multiple mail providers

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am working on a solution in java where I need to read new messages from different email accounts (accounts with different email providers).

The current approach that I follow is by running a cron job to open these email accounts and run a loop on the inbox to get the new emails into my system.

Is there a best practice solution available for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It is more elegant to to make the code handle only one mailbox, and make the configurations come from properties file.

-Create a properties file for each mailbox with all the configurations (protocol / server / account / password etc)

-Create a cron for each mailbox with his properties file in the classpath.

This way, it is much easier to maintain: 
-you have easy way to remove or add new mailboxes without rewrite code, 
-easy to handle issues- seperete log file for each mailbox, 
-everything is more simple (no need to think about multithreading)